# How to implement face recognition authentication in React-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, authentication, authorization

I am new in react native. I want to implement face id and touch id authentication in my app. In my app touch id is working. But face id is not working. my code for face id authentication is below :

```
 callFinger(isLogin) {
    TouchID.isSupported()
        .then(biometryType => {

            if (biometryType === 'TouchID') {

                TouchID.authenticate('Unlock with your fingerprint').then(success => {
                    if (success) {
                        if (isLogin == "true")
                            this.callRedirect(isLogin);
                        else
                            this.callLoginApi();
                    }
                }
                );
            } else if (biometryType === 'FaceID') {
                 TouchID.authenticate('Unlock with your FaceID').then(success => {
                    if (success) {
                        if (isLogin == "true")
                            this.callRedirect(isLogin);
                        else
                            this.callLoginApi();
                    }
                }
                );
            } else if (biometryType === true) {

                TouchID.authenticate('Unlock with your fingerprint').then(success => {
                    if (success) {
                        if (isLogin == "true")
                            this.callRedirect(isLogin);
                        else
                            this.callLoginApi();
                    }
                }
                );
            }
            else {
                this.callRedirect(isLogin);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.callRedirect(isLogin);
        })

}
```

I am using this link for touch Id and it's work for me. but in this link face id code not working. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-touch-id

I also refere below link but it's also not working.
https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id/blob/master/examples/BiometricAuthExample/App.js

Answer (score -1):

You probably alredy have the solution, but if someone else is facing the same issue...

Try to add this pair of key/string in your `ios/<YourPoject>/info.plist`

```
<key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
<string>Enabling Face ID allows you quick and secure access to your account.</string>
```